# AES CS2Padding for java

Tags: java, security, encryption, aes, jce

I'm trying to establish encrypted connection between my MCU device which running on (Cortex m3 STM32f102 controller) and my java application server. When i'm using plain text without encryption all works fine. 
The problem is that when i using encryption (AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING on my server) i have  BadPaddingException error when i receive message. When i looked into datasheets for MCU's crypto library i saw mention, that

> 2. In CBC mode and in case of a call where P_inputSize is greater than 16 and not multiple 
>      of 16, Ciphertext Stealing will be activated. See CBC-CS2 of <"SP 800-38 A - Addendum"> 
>      NIST SP 800-38A Addendum

I think that problem is in different padding algorithms for controller and server.

Is there some implementation of  AES/CBC with CS2 padding for java?
Or how would you recommend me to solve this problem?

---

As recommended in posts below, i changed my encryption to AES\CTR\NoPadding and now it works.

Comment: May I suggest a change: from `CS2Padding` to `CTS mode` or similar. I don't think I've ever come across `CS2Padding`. I think more folks will recognize `CTS mode`.

Comment: @jww Nice point, i need to try this

Comment: The JCE supports a CTS mode, but it doesn't really define it anywhere that I can find. I would try something like `Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTS/NOPADDING")`

Comment: Cipher section in [JCA standard names document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#Cipher) contains subsection for modes, where CTS is mentioned since at least [java 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#Cipher).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As recommended in posts below, i changed my encryption to AES\CTR\NoPadding and now it works.